# Is it well-defined to use a pointer pointing to one-past-new and one-past-new[]?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, bounds, dynamic-allocation

As per n4296, Section 5.7/4

> Moreover, if the expression `P` points to the last element of an array object, the expression `(P)+1` points one past the last element of the array object, and if the expression `Q` points one past the last element of an array object, the expression `(Q)-1` points to the last element of the array object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

In C++, it's perfectly well to have a pointer pointing to one past the last element of an array and use it in pointer arithmetics:

```
int a[5], *p = a+5;
std::ptrdiff_t d = p-a; // Guaranteed to be 5
```

Even iterators from containers support this behavior:

```
std::vector<int> vec(5);
std::ptrdiff_t diff = vec.end()-vec.begin(); // Guaranteed to be 5
```

My question is, does this apply to dynamically allocated memory? Consider the following examples:

Case 1: `new`

```
int *a = new int, p = a+1;
std::ptrdiff_t diff = p-a; // Well-defined?
delete a;
```

Case 2: `new[]`

```
int *a = new int[5], p = a+5;
std::ptrdiff_t diff = p-a; // Well-defined?
delete[] a;
```

I suppose case 1 is UB while case 2 is well-defined. But what exactly is defined by the ISO 14882 standard?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's exactly what I suspect. Can you provide proof?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this should cover everything.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I don't think so. This question focuses more on dynamic allocation, while the dupe soruce focuses more on a single object.

Comment: @iBug It is a single object either way, how would its storage duration change that?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight C++11 5.7 [expr.add]/4: "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the
first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type." So there is no UB there.

Comment: I suspect that all that is guaranteed by the "new" operator is that there is that adding one more element wouldn't cause the pointer to wrap around (and thus break relational operators).  On the other hand, adding a few billion to the pointer could easily cause problems on a 32-bit machine.